# How to read LZO compressed HDFS files in Giraph

Tags: giraph

I am looking for an input format for Giraph which can read LZO compressed files.  It appears the current input format GiraphRunner uses by default is BspInputFormat which has no mention of LZO compression.  Is this simply an oversight and I'll have to implement my own LzoBspInputFormat class?  It feels like something someone has already done previously.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I asked this before actually even trying.  I am loading LZO compressed files into my Giraph job via the GiraphRunner and it is accepting the input fine.  This was a complete non-issue.